# How to change what I've set a key to do in ahk

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make a script for a game called Hearthstone. The script will be used to press a certain button and play a certain card. The only problem I have is that the cards change position based on how many you have. So I want to know how I could make buttons to choose the amount of cards in my hand.

I've come across the Hotkeys command but it seems to be more of a toggle thing. All the cards are bound from 1-10 and was thinking that I could make it so ^1-^10 represents how many cards I have but I don't know how I could do that.

Comment: "I could make it ^1-^10 to change number of cards" yes, you could do that. It's not clear what is your question.

Comment: edited to make more sense

Comment: Not to me, sorry. You can do `^1::numCards=1` and so on is this the question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a step towards what I want. I'm pretty new to ahk so I'll do some reading on if statements and variables within ahk and see if I can work it out.

Comment: You're probably going to want to look up the Window Spy tool in AutoHotkey, and get used to controlling keyboard and/or mouse movements/clicks before asking for help here. Once you've got some basics of the script mocked up, we might be able to offer up some better assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oleg's comment was more of my answer than I thought.

setting ^1 to `^1::numCards=1` and so on, I was able to set an if statement to do what I wanted something to do when the variable `numCards` equated to different things. Such as: 
1:
`if numCards = 1
{
    do thing
}
return`

and so on...